# Determination of tangential and binormal vectors

Tags: vectors, orthonormal

I am struggling to find binormal and tangential vector, which are both perpendicular to normal vector, which I have found.

So I have a right-hand system ($\mathbf{e_x,e_y,e_z}$), there is a sketch bellow.

[image]

As is seen, there is a surface. I need to find a normal vector, tangential vector and binormal vector on the surface ${\xi(x,z)}$. Bellow is another sketch:

[image]

Normal vector ${\bf{n}}$ can be found from the following formulas: $${\bf{n}=\frac{\nabla F}{|\nabla F|}},$$ where ${\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}}$ and ${F}$ is the equation of surface $${F=y-\nabla \xi(x,z)}$$.

So, components of the ${\bf{n}}$ is:

$${\mathbf{n}(-\frac{\frac{\partial \xi(x,z)}{\partial x}}{a}\mathbf{e_x},\frac{1}{a}\mathbf{e_y}, -\frac{\frac{\partial \xi(x,z)}{\partial z}}{a}\mathbf{e_z})},$$

where ${a=\sqrt{1+(\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x})^2+(\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z})^2}}$.

Now, I need to find ${\mathbf{ \gamma }}$, ${\mathbf {\tau} }$. Since all vectors are perpendicular to each other and one another can be found through the vector multiplication we could use the following set of equations:

$${{\mathbf{\tau} \cdot \mathbf{n} = n_x \tau_x + n_y \tau_y + n_z \tau_z  =0}}$$
$${{\mathbf{\gamma} \cdot \mathbf{n} = n_x \gamma_x + n_y \gamma_y + n_z \gamma_z  =0}}$$
$${{\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{\gamma}  =\mathbf{\tau}}}$$

The last vector equation can be expand into 3 equations if we equate corresponding projections:

$${n_y \gamma_z - n_z \gamma_y = \tau_x},$$

$${n_z \gamma_x - n_x \gamma_z = \tau_y},$$

$${n_x \gamma_y - n_y \gamma_x = \tau_z},$$

So we get a set of 5 equations and 6 variables: ${\tau_x , \tau_y, \tau_z, \gamma_x, \gamma_y, \gamma_z}$.

As far as I understand, vectors ${\mathbf{\tau}}$ and ${\mathbf{\gamma}}$ must be unit, so it gives two additional equations:

$${\tau_x^2 + \tau_y^2 + \tau_z^2} = 1,$$
$${\gamma_x^2 + \gamma_y^2 + \gamma_z^2} = 1.$$

That is all in common leads to the following equations set:

$${-\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \tau_x + \tau_y - \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} \tau_z = 0 },$$

$${-\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \gamma_x + \gamma_y - \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} \gamma_z = 0 },$$

$${\gamma_z + \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} \gamma_y = a \tau_x, }$$

$${ - \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} \gamma_x + \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \gamma_z = a \tau_y, }$$

$${ -\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} \gamma_y - \gamma_x = a \tau_z, }$$

$${\tau_x^2 + \tau_y^2 + \tau_z^2} = 1,$$
$${\gamma_x^2 + \gamma_y^2 + \gamma_z^2} = 1.$$

It is not only 7 equations for 6 variables, but the system is incompatible..

What am I missing? Where is the wrong assumption?..

Comment: Note that $${{\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{\gamma}  =\mathbf{\tau}}} \implies {{\mathbf{\tau} \cdot \mathbf{n} = n_x \tau_x + n_y \tau_y + n_z \tau_z  =0}}$$ therefore we don't need the second equation. Morover also$$ {{-\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{\gamma}  =\mathbf{\tau}}} $$ is fine if you are not interested to a specific orientation.

Comment: Note also that fon $n$ and $\gamma$ unitary $${{\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{\gamma}  =\mathbf{\tau}}} \implies {\tau_x^2 + \tau_y^2 + \tau_z^2} = 1$$ therefore you need to reduce the number of equations.

Comment: @user So, I must exclude equation number one and two in my final set, since they bring nothing new, right? So I have 5 equations now and 6 variables. 
You also wrote that there are free parameters to choice? How many and why there are tunable variables?..

Comment: If we fix the orientation such that ${{\mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{\gamma}  =\mathbf{\tau}}}$, then we only need to fix $\gamma$ which, at the end, is determined by a single parameter (that is an angle in the plane orthogonal to $n$). Therefore $5$ equations now and $6$ variables seems correct.

Comment: In my process, we have $2$ free variables for $\Gamma$ but by the condition that $|\gamma|=1$.

Comment: …this condition reduces to one free variable (with the orientation fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $$\vec n=(n_1,n_2,n_3)$$ we can take for example $$\vec \gamma=\left(\frac{n_2}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}},-\frac{n_1}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2}},0\right)$$ such that $\vec n \cdot \vec \gamma =0$ and finally $$\vec \tau = \vec n \times \vec \gamma$$

---

More in general to obtain all the possible solutions, assuming wlog $n_3 \neq 0$, $\vec \tau$ and $\vec \gamma$ are unit vectors lying on the plane $n_1x+n_2y+n_3z=0$, we can then set $\vec \Gamma =(\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,\Gamma_3)$ such that

$$n_1\Gamma_1+n_2\Gamma_2+n_3\Gamma_3=0 \implies \Gamma_3=-\frac{n_1\Gamma_1+n_2\Gamma_2}{n_3}$$

$$ \implies \vec \Gamma =\left(\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2,-\frac{n_1\Gamma_1+n_2\Gamma_2}{n_3}\right),\;\;\vec \gamma = \frac{\vec \Gamma}{\left|\vec \Gamma\right|}$$

and finally $$\vec \tau = \pm\; \vec n \times \vec \gamma$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It might be right, but it looks a bit tricky since we manually set ${\gamma_z=0}$. I just want to get all vectors components based on pure calculations without manual zero setting...

Comment: @John More in general $\tau$ and $\gamma$ are unit vectors lying on the plane $n_1x+n_2y+n_3z=0$. Therefore we can fix $\gamma$ and then find $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you! Can we somehow do it without setting some components to zero? Could you also take a closer look at my assumptions in the question? Can I find it all in my way somehow?

Comment: @John Meanwhile I've added a generalization of the method to find all the solutions, note that we have $2$ free parameters to determine $\gamma$ and $2$ choice for $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I marked your response as an accepted answer. May I ask you, is it possible to find a new basis using Lamé coefficients ?

Comment: I take a look on that! Bye